# Leer archivo de texto desde JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando crear una función que lea todo el contenido de un archivo de texto y luego lo visualice todo en una nueva ventana. Por ahora este es mi código:

```
function leeArchivo(file)
        {
            var archivo = new XMLHttpRequest();
            archivo.open("GET", file, false);
            archivo.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if(archivo.readyState === 4)
                {
                    if(archivo.status === 200 || archivo.status == 0)
                    {
                        var Texto = archivo.responseText;
                        myWindow.document.write (Texto);
                    }
                }
            }
            archivo.send(null);
        }
```

Llamo a la función mas adelante pasando como parámetro la ruta de mi archivo:

```
leerArchivo("prueba.txt");
```

El problema está en que  así se visualiza la ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me gustaría que se viese como un archivo de texto normal, sin los datos de arriba y con el espaciado correspondiente.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: El problema es que no estás leyendo un archivo de texto, sino un archivo RTF (probablemente Word). Lo que muestras es el contenido; Javascript no te lo va mostar igual que lo hace MSWord porque MSWord tiene lógica que interpreta esos comandos como instrucciones de visualización.

Comment: Supongo que se trata de un JSON. Si el JSON tiene formato podrías probar `myWindow.document.write ("<pre>"+Texto+"</pre>");` Mira por favor este ejemplo: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/project/editor/cfda78f587ebe39902c470e719cfd7e3